# NUnit Tests won't run because of "System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly X"

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, nunit, .net-assembly

I'm using Visual Basic .Net, .NET-Verion 4.6.1, VS 2019 Community.

I want to include Unittests in my project so I istalled NUnit, created a Test-Project, imported the project I want to test, call a class in the project and I get:

`SetUp failed for test fixture *Project*_Test.*Class*_Test
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system can't find the required file.`

So I searched around and installed the Config-Manager with Nuget-Console -> didn't do anything.
... copied the Config-Manager.dll from the project to my test-project -> different fileNotFound exception. This time it wants the next file.

So I debugged and saw, that the error originates on this line of code

`Private ReadOnly STR_CONNECTION_STRING As String = DirectCast(New Global.System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader().GetValue("*DB_Conn_String*", GetType(String)), String)`

How do I remove this error? The line of code doesn't seem to be the problem, since the test can't find the classes in the first place.

Thx for the help
Daedra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I spend a good day to figure this out:

If you use .NET-Framework for the project, you want to write tests for, you **don't** want to go

`Add
  -> New Project
  -> NUnit Test (.Net-Core)`

You run into unlimited problems with .NET-Core vs .NET-Framework.

Instead do

`Add
  -> New Project
  -> Class-Library (.NET-Framework)`

Then go to NuGet and install *NUnit* and *NUnit3TestAdapter*.

I simply copied my already written tests and they worked instantly.

Hope this helps someone someday ^~^

Cheers Daedra